# Find string with most frequency of a character in List of strings using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list

I am dealing with binary vectors so each `string` in a `List<string>` looks like

```
vectors[0] = "1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1"; 
vectors[1] = "1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1";
```

I want to get the biggest string from the `List<string>`, with most number of 1's.

Comment: I'm confused, is your desired result `vectors[0]` or `1 1 1` from `vectors[0]`?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: Does the `1` position influence to this weight?

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff anything, index or string or count. Just want a one liner solution to find the biggest string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like the provided solutions here are way too complicated.
So here is mine:

```
vectors.OrderByDescending(v => v.Count(c => c == '1')).First();
```

Note that Count is only evaluated once per "Vector". [EnumerableSorter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2518) does this for you.

If you want a more performant solution then go with [@octavioccls answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36920161/1789202)

Comment: Yup, the simplest answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this:

```
var biggest= vectors.Select(v=> new {Vector = v, Count = v.Count(c => c=='1')})
                    .Aggregate((seed, current) => seed.Count < current.Count ? current:seed)
                    .Vector;
```

You can also use `OrderBy` extension method but `Aggregate` is O(n) while `OrderBy` is O(n* log n).

I  first call `Select` extension to avoid calculate multiple times the amount of 1's of `seed`:

```
var biggest= vectors.Aggregate((seed, current)=>seed.Count(c=>c=='1')<current.Count(c=>c=='1')?current:seed);
```

Comment: @Charpie  I don't see why is so complicated, is a matter of opinion I think, but is a valid solution, I don't know why was downvoted

Comment: @octavioccl - because you are using Aggregate instead of orderby or max

Comment: `Aggregate` is more efficient than `OrderBy`,  OrderBy is O(n* log n)

Comment: +1 for considering complexity. I do have a large dataset (~ 100k vectors) so I will try comparing the simplest answer (vectors.OrderByDescending(v => v.Count(c => c == '1')).First()) with this one on the basis of performance.

Comment: @TahaRehmanSiddiqui If you have large data set and do care about performance, you should not be using LINQ at all - a simple `foreach` will outperform all the posted LINQ solutions.

Comment: Good point @IvanStoev. Kind of ignored that before, thanks for bringing to light. In the end I would still keep the linq code for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Count()` method:

```
int index = 0;
int max = vectors[0].Count(x => x == '1');

for (int a = 1; a < vectors.Length; a++)
{
    var count = vectors[a].Count(x => x == '$');
    if (count > max)
    {
        max = count;
        index = a;
    }
}
```

after loop you will have index of string which has maximum '1'

Comment: why the extra loop why not just `int max = vectors[0].Count(x => x == '1').max(x => x)

Comment: I wanted a one liner solution that why I mentioned LINQ in the title. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ

```
var result = vectors.Select(d => new { Item = d,
                                       OneCount = d.Split(' ').Count(y => y == "1")})
                    .OrderByDescending(t => t.OneCount)
                    .Select(k=>k.Item).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: There is no need to split, just count the char '1' in each vector. Also Count is only evaluated once per vector so you dont have to "cache" its result in an annonymous type.

Answer (score 1):

```
vectors.OrderByDescending(b => b.Split('1').Length).First()
```

Comment: No need to use split when you only want to count. Also this method returns a wrong result (it should be Length-1)

Comment: length-1 :P what difference does that make ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a loop on the list and for each string calculate the number of occurences of '1' in this way:

```
int count = myString.Split('1').Length - 1;
```

Then store a temporary variable with the local maximum and the number of string with that maximum.
Like this:

```
int max = list[0].Split('1').Length - 1;
int stringMax = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < list.Length; i++)
{
    var count = list[i].Split('1').Length - 1;
    if (count > max)
    {
        max = count;
        stringMax = i;
    }
}
```

At the end *stringMax* is the string with max value and *max* is that value

Comment: I wanted a one liner solution that why I mentioned LINQ in the title. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
var vectors = new[] { 
    "1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1",
    "1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1",
};
var q = from v in vectors
        select new
        {
            v,
            c = v.Split(' ').Count(b => b == "1"),
        };
var m = q.First(c => c.c == q.Max(b => b.c)).v;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var vectors = new List<string>();
        vectors.Add("1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1"); 
        vectors.Add("1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1");


        foreach(var v in vectors)
        {
            var result = new List<string>();
            int max = 0;
            foreach(var c in v)
            {
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.ToString().Trim())) continue;
                //Console.Write(c);
                //Console.Write(max);
                if(c != '1')
                {
                    max = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    max++;
                    if(max > result.Count)
                    {
                        result.Add(c.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Final Result: " + string.Join(" ", result));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted a one liner solution that why I mentioned LINQ in the title. Thanks anyways.